# Differences between Breuer Tanachim

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition, writing-printing

I stayed with Dr. Gabriel Wasserman for Shabbos over the summer and he mentioned that the different editions of R' Mordochai Breuer's זצ"ל Tana"ch have some small differences (eg. the Mosad Harav Kook edition, the Keter, *et cetera*). He also mentioned that one follows the notes in the Jellen/Yellen Tana"ch, although I could find nothing when I looked into this.

Is there anything online which goes through the main differences between R' Breuer's different Tanachim ?

Comment: The biggest difference by far is the parshiyot in daat mikra are based on Leningrad because the Yellin Tanach hadn't been found yet. The very very few spelling differences are mostly detailed in R' Breuer's article מקראות שיש להם הכרע or something like that. Shabbat Shalom Noach

Comment: R' Breuer updated his work, when new materials surfaced. It is hinted here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Breuer#Literary_contribution R' Yellin's Tanakh is available here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Yellin_Tanakh.pdf